# LWJGL Display.update() too slow - driver issue?

Tags: java, performance, time, lwjgl

I have a Problem on an other PC (not that one im always working on) with the following Code:

```
public void run(){
        initStuff();
        initWindow();
        initGl();
        initTextures();
        initParticles();
        long lastFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long thisFrame;
        long delta;
        long time;
        while(true){
            glPushMatrix();
            thisFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();
            delta = thisFrame - lastFrame;
            lastFrame = thisFrame;
            System.out.println("[start loop] (last loop took " + delta + " ms)");
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("---clearing");
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            System.out.println("------myupdating (clearing took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms)");
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            myupdate();
            System.out.println("---------painting (mydating took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms)");
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            draw();
            System.out.println("------------syncing (painting took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms)");
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Display.sync(60);
            System.out.println("---------------disp updating (syncing took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms)");
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Display.update();
            System.out.println("------------------[end loop] (updating took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms)");
            glPopMatrix();
        }
//      Display.destroy();
    }

    private void myupdate(){

    }

    private void draw(){
        background.use();
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex2d(0, 0);
            glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            glVertex2d(800, 0);
            glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex2d(800, 600);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex2d(0, 600);
        glEnd();
        for(Particle p: particles){
            p.getTexture().use();
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
                glVertex2d(p.getX(), p.getY());
                glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
                glVertex2d(p.getX() + p.getWidth(), p.getY());
                glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
                glVertex2d(p.getX() + p.getWidth(), p.getY() + p.getHeight());
                glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
                glVertex2d(p.getX(), p.getY() + p.getHeight());
            glEnd();
            p.setX(p.getX() + 1);
        }
```

So, I added all the time outputs to look where it slows down like this - the Answer is Display.update(). Following output:

```
[start loop] (last loop took 340 ms)
---clearing
------myupdating (clearing took 0 ms)
---------painting (mydating took 0 ms)
------------syncing (painting took 11 ms)
---------------disp updating (syncing took 0 ms)
------------------[end loop] (updating took 330 ms)
[start loop] (last loop took 341 ms)
---clearing
------myupdating (clearing took 0 ms)
---------painting (mydating took 0 ms)
------------syncing (painting took 12 ms)
---------------disp updating (syncing took 0 ms)
------------------[end loop] (updating took 332 ms)
[start loop] (last loop took 345 ms)
---clearing
------myupdating (clearing took 0 ms)
---------painting (mydating took 0 ms)
------------syncing (painting took 12 ms)
---------------disp updating (syncing took 0 ms)
------------------[end loop] (updating took 331 ms)
[start loop] (last loop took 343 ms)
---clearing
------myupdating (clearing took 0 ms)
---------painting (mydating took 0 ms)
------------syncing (painting took 12 ms)
---------------disp updating (syncing took 0 ms)
```

So, you see theres something wrong. But what? Contains my Code bad mistakes? I have no idea... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Besides that you use heavily outdated OpenGL functionality, you set the frame-rate to 60 FPS. This will cause `Display.update()` to block while waiting for the vertical retrace (vsync) during full-screen, which is "working as intended".

In addition many OpenGL functions are "cached" and not immediately executed as one would expect, but internally optimized by the driver and executed at a convenient point (latest at `Display.update()`). This usually improves performance and throughput, but as well means that measuring the time of a single OpenGL function becomes close to impossible.

Comment: 60 FPS = 16.67 ms per frame, not the measured 300 ms. I guess that the CPU-GPU bus is too slow on that particular system to be able to transmit each particle every frame.

Comment: Likely, but it is difficult to pinpoint that thanks to caching.

Comment: So, what i have to do now? When i remove sync(), its almost the same.

Comment: Less particles and switch to modern OpenGL (3.0 or higher).